# cut and paste range vba

Tags: vba, excel

```
    For j = 1 To numrows - 1
        erow = Cells(Rows.count, 10 + j).End(xlUp).Row
        totalMins = Cells(erow, 10 + j)
        MsgBox (totalMins)
        Range(Cells(erow, 10 + j), Cells(erow, 10 + j).End(xlUp)).Cut
        Cells(20, 20).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next
```

Keep getting pastespecial range class failed error. what is the reason this is failing and how could I correct my code.

Comment: I don't think you can paste just the values using cut.

Comment: ok yea ill just clear the contents to accomplish the same task. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't paste special from a cut. Use:

```
    For j = 1 To numrows - 1
       erow = Cells(Rows.count, 10 + j).End(xlUp).Row
       totalMins = Cells(erow, 10 + j)
       MsgBox (totalMins)
       Range(Cells(erow, 10 + j), Cells(erow, 10 + j).End(xlUp)).Cut Cells(20, 20)
    Next
```

Or better yet:

```
    For j = 1 To numrows - 1
       erow = Cells(Rows.count, 10 + j).End(xlUp).Row
       totalMins = Cells(erow, 10 + j)
       MsgBox (totalMins)
       Cells(20, 20) =Range(Cells(erow, 10 + j), Cells(erow, 10 + j).End(xlUp))
       Range(Cells(erow, 10 + j), Cells(erow, 10 + j).End(xlUp)).ClearContents
    Next
```